# Est-il correct d'utiliser "l'autre" dans une liste de plus de deux éléments ?

Tags: style-de-rédaction, énumération

Je dois faire une liste de 4 exemples et chacun est décrit dans un paragraphe.

Je me demande si je peux commencer mes paragraphes par :

> - Le premier exemple…
> - L'autre exemple…
> - L'autre exemple encore…
> - L'autre élément enfin…

Est que je peux utiliser plusieurs fois "L'autre" ou est-ce que cette formulation ne convient pas (parce qu'elle sous-entend qu'il y aurait seulement deux exemples)?

Answer (score 2):

***L'autre*** est inadapté car comme il y a plus d'un autre, l'article défini est déroutant.

Tu peux bien sûr utiliser les ordinaux :

> le premier exemple, le **deuxième**, le troisième, ...

ou alors, si tu ne souhaites pas le faire pour une raison ou pour une autre, tu peux utiliser **suivant** qui ne présente pas ce problème :

> le premier, le **suivant**, le suivant encore, le suivant toujours, et enfin le dernier.

Comment: Si la répétition ne fait pas peur à l'OP (après tout la question d'origine en use) et même si c'est inélégant, on pourrait aussi remplace "le" par "un", mais vos propositions sont effectivement bien plus agréables.